# I am trying to reverse complement a fasta DNA sequence

Tags: python, reverse, fasta, dna-sequence, complement

I have been trying to reverse complement a fasta DNA sequence. Here is my code:

```
fastafile=open('sequence (3).fasta','r')
entries=[]
reverse=""
sequence=['A','T','G','C','N']
for line in fastafile:
    if not line.startswith('>'):
        line = line.split()
        entries.append(line)
print entries
for index in range(0,len(entries[::-1])):
    if index !=sequence:
        print "this is not a valid nucleotide"
        break
    else:
        if index=='A':
            reverse+='T'
        elif index=='T':
            reverse+='A'
        elif index=='C':
            reverse+='G'
        elif index=='G':
            reverse+ 'C'
        elif index=='N':
            reverse+='N'
print reverse
```

And each time I get the output, this is not a valid nucleotide, even when my print of entries show that it has the items in sequence. Here is a sample of the output when I print enteries;

```
[['GCTCCCCTGAGGTTCGGCACCCACACTCCCTTCCCAGGAGCTCGCGATGCAAGAGCCACAGTCAGAGCTC'], ['AATATCGACCCCCCTCTGAGCCAGGAGACATTTTCAGAATTGTGGAACCTGCTTCCTGAAAACAATGTTC'], ['TGTCTTCGGAGCTGTGCCCAGCAGTGGATGAGCTGCTGCTCCCAGAGAGCGTCGTGAACTGGCTAGACGA']
```

How can I override this problem? I just want to add that I only started seriously programming with python about 2 months ago so I am still learning and improving.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop statement is:

```
for index in range(0,len(entries[::-1])):
```

This will iterate over the length of entries, that is, `0, 1, 2, 3, ..., len(entries)`.

When you do `if index != sequence` you are actually comparing an integer with a list, say `if 3 != ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G']`. I assume you can see that makes no sense. What you probably want to do is see if the nucleotide in the sequence is a valid nucleotide, ergo it is in the `sequence` list. You can do it like this:

```
if entries[::-1][index] in sequence # Will be true if the nucleotide at entries[::-1][index] is inside sequence
```

Let me say two things:

- First one, you don't have to range to `len(entries[::-1])`, it is the same as `len(entries)`
- Secondly, and more important, there is an actual module build specially for bioinformatics. It is called [Biopython](http://biopython.org/). It has special objects and functions. For example, your problem could be resolved as follows:

-

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq

dna = Seq("ATGGCCATTGTAATGGGCCGCTGAAAGGGTGCCCGATAG")
print dna.reverse_complement()
```

**Output:** `CTATCGGGCACCCTTTCAGCGGCCCATTACAATGGCCAT`

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I am not as familiar with majority of the biopython modules but seq requires I input a string of nucleotide sequence where as in my case I want to use a fasta sequence from a file as an input.